# Выбор паттерна проектирования

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования

Столкнулся с реальной проблемой, как по мне!
Кроме как с паттерном `MVC` я больше ни с каким работать не научен и никогда не работал. `MVC` мне не подходит.
Ниже опишу принцип работы, по которому будет работать сайт!

Сайт будет динамическим. Если браузер поддерживает `history API` то сайт будет работать динамически, а если нет поддержки (или на сайт зашел, например, поисковик) то сайт будет работать не динамически. То-есть, смысл в том, чтобы через этот паттерн было удобно строит сразу динамический сайт, так и с полной перезагрузкой страниц.

Те у кого есть опыт в создании подобных проектов, поделитесь пожалуйста.
Какой паттер выбрать? Так чтобы удобно было с шаблонами (версткой) работать, чтобы не приходилось одну и ту же верстку писать по 2 и более раз. Чтобы все аккуратно и красиво было)

Сайт будет строиться на `PHP` / `JS` / `MySQL` без всякой установки каких либо модулей на сервер и прочего!

Comment: А что именно вы понимаете под "_паттерном проектирования_" в контексте вопроса? И в чем причина ограничения на сторонние модули/библиотеки?

Comment: MVC тут вообще ни при чём.

Comment: Концепция MVC не имеет отношения к паттернам проектирования. Чтобы понять паттерны для JS, почитайте эту книгу: http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/6287517/

Comment: @IonDen, вы не правы. MVC это вполне себе паттерн проектирования. Более того, именно в этом качестве он описанн у Мартина Фаулера, [вот здесь](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/modelViewController.html).

Comment: Другой момент, что вопрос совсем не о паттерне проектирования, а о построении правильной архитектуры приложения.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, хотя знаете, не уверен что именно так. Я всегда считал что паттерны проектирования, это просто способы организации кода в проекте. А MVC это уже более высокий уровень абстракции, относящийся к принципам работы приложения.

Comment: Ну так а чем MVC в таком раскладе не устраивает? Да и MVC это не паттерн, а схема или еще можно сказать концепция организации работы компонентов, в которых уже могут применены разлишные паттерны.

Answer (score 2):

Вам просто нужно свое "если" реализовать в роутингах и редиректить запрос на контроллер который будет обрабатывать нужный вам вариант. Паттерны проектирования к данному вопросу не имеют отношения.

Answer (score 0):

Делайте динамический сайт с помощью любимого JS фреймворка (Backbone, Angular, Ember), и используйте [Prerender.io](https://prerender.io/) как сервис, или на своём сервере – для генерации соответствующих статических страниц для поисковиков.

Comment: А изоморфные JS приложения уже не в моде? ;)